# Problem plotting curve with smooth option

Tags: plot, latex

this is twice the same graph, except one is smoothed.
If you compile it, you will see.

```
\documentclass[
]{scrreprt}     
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scatter/classes={%
1={mark=diamond*,draw=black},
0={mark=o,draw=black}},
yticklabels={},ytick style = {draw=none},  xticklabels={},xtick style = {draw=none},
xmin=0,
xmax=200,
ymin=0,
ymax=11,
width=12cm,
height=7cm]
\addplot[smooth,black]
coordinates{
            (0,10)
            (10,1)
            (200,0.1)
            };
            
\addplot[ dashed, black]
        coordinates{
            (0,10)
            (10,1)
            (200,0.1)
            };
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

What I actually trying to achieve is that the second data point gives a smooth curve.
But using option smooth as you can see absolutely doesn't do the job here.
I tried with many more data points but nothing worked, this just gave me weird results. Also the approximation from the second to the last data point doesn't work as intended.

If you ask how it actually should look like, google Goodfellow generalization.
I want to draw this comparison between training and generalization error.

Every advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you draw a sketch of how the resulting image should look like? Maybe you want to play around with the tension? `\addplot[smooth,black,tension={0.15}]`

Comment: Thank you very much, this basically solved my problem. I didn't know there was this additional option because so far, smooth alone has always been enough. I should probably look at the documentation more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the level of smoothness with the `tension` parameter:

```
\documentclass[
]{scrreprt}     
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scatter/classes={%
1={mark=diamond*,draw=black},
0={mark=o,draw=black}},
yticklabels={},ytick style = {draw=none},  xticklabels={},xtick style = {draw=none},
xmin=0,
xmax=200,
ymin=0,
ymax=11,
width=12cm,
height=7cm]
\addplot[smooth,black,tension={0.15}]
coordinates{
            (0,10)
            (10,1)
            (200,0.1)
            };
            
\addplot[ dashed, black]
        coordinates{
            (0,10)
            (10,1)
            (200,0.1)
            };
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```